# error during installing visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2017 RC and I keep getting this error:

> [2ea4:002f][2016-11-20T21:47:00] Package
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OfficeIntegration.Resources,version=15.108.25831.0,chip=x64,language=en-US'
>   failed to install. MSI:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OfficeIntegration.Resources,version=15.108.25831.0,chip=x64,language=en-US\tfs_officeIntegrationCoreRes.msi,
>   Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 
>   MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  USING_EXUIH="1" , Return code: 1714, Details: The
>   older version of Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2017
>   RC Office Integration Language Pack (x64) - ENU cannot be removed. 
>   Contact your technical support group.

Answer (score 7):

We were able to force uninstall the problematic package using [this Microsoft tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed), after which we were able to install VS2017 normally.

The package name in our case was: **Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2017 RC Office Integration Language Pack (x64) - ENU​**

Comment: More info can be found here as well: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24352/vs2017-installer-fails-trying-to-update-package-mi.html

Answer (score 3):

With my experience, this happens when Visual Studio 2017 setup cannot uninstall/repair/upgrade an existing package. Try this:

1. Quit the VS 2017 installer setup and go to this location "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OfficeIntegration.Resources"
2. There must be an .msi file with name "tfs_officeIntegrationCoreRes.msi" (based on your error message - it appears that you have office tools installed as part of previous VS installation)
3. Run that msi and remove the component (there must be a remove option). Once done restart the VS 2017 setup again and this time you shouldnt get this error at least.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Running that MSI simply tells me to run a setup.exe instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the issue after having installed VS 2017 Professional then trying to "upgrade" to Enterprise.

Comment: If running the msi doesn't show an option to uninstall, try right clicking.

Comment: It's not working for me. Running the .msi ends with "Please run setup"

Comment: I've run into this error and when I tried running the MSI it also told me to run setup.exe instead. Finally I looked at the error details and it was erroring on creating a registry key.

Answer (score 0):

after several tries, I had no solution. Then restarted the computer and run the installer again. No installation errors :)